# How to output woocommerce products to a page, style and modify the html structure

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, hooks

I am a complete noob when it comes to woocommerce so bear with me. I have added 6 products into woo. I have a cart and a checkout page that are using shortcodes to output the php/html to those respective pages, now I know I can *Edit files in an upgrade-safe way using overrides* per the woo documentation. I have successfully modified these pages using that technique.

Also I am using the [understrap-child](https://github.com/understrap/understrap-child) theme, since it is custom do I need to add `add_theme_support` in my functions.php? as described in the woo docs.

Now getting to what I want to achieve. I want to create a new page in wordpress, lets call it `all-products` I want to loop through all my products and display them on the page, I also want to access the php file that I can overide html and php for that page, How would I do this. I don't see a shortcode to output all my products. This is where I am stuck. I can clarify this question if it is not clear enough. Would I create a `page-products` in my theme and use a theming snippet like below?

```
<ul class="products">
    <?php
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'product',
            'posts_per_page' => 12
            );
        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
        if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
            while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
                wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
            endwhile;
        } else {
            echo __( 'No products found' );
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>
</ul><!--/.products-->
```

Also is it better to use hooks to overide certain templates as described [here](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/introduction-to-hooks-actions-and-filters/) could someone explain how do this hooks thing, I don't quite get where the code ends up.

Thanks! ahead of time.

Comment: you need to learn woocommerce tamplate and hook to design and manipulate woocommerce customization from woocommerce docs. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a product listing page on your site, you just create a normal page in the admin.  Then in the admin go to WooCommerce > Settings > Products > General and select that page for the "Shop Page" setting.

If you want a custom product page you could do basically what your saying above.  Create a new page in the admin, say its called My Products.  Then you could use a page template called page-my-products.php and you could include your query in that template.